# Rotate, align and compare DICOM image

Tags: image, matlab, rotation, alignment

Having 2 DICOM images, one is from a CT and the other from an MRI, I need to rotate these images so that they are aligned in such a way that the hole in the center of the phantom is aligned with the hole above in the "x" coordinate, then I need my origin of coordinates to be the coordinates of said central hole and from that origin to obtain the coordinates of the other holes and to be able to compare those of the CT with the MRI[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGwsL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzA6K.png)

I have this code where I rotate the image by hand by putting about 8º of rotation, which as I explained should be done only by aligning the central hole with the one above, then the code locates all the holes and gives me the coordinates that are passed from pixel to mm and finally graph them. I would need to change the origin to the central hole and order and compare the coordinates of each hole.

```
clear all
close all
clc
I=dicomread('MR_T2_AX.dcm');
I=imrotate(I,8);
figure(1);imshow(I,[]);
umb=graythresh(I);
bw=im2bw(I,umb);
bw=not(bw);
s=strel('disk',1);
bw=imdilate(bw,s);
figure(2);imshow(bw,[]);
[L Ne]=bwlabel(bw);
prop=regionprops(L);
r=find([prop.Area]<100);
g=find([prop.Area]>100);
%encontrar los círculos con área pequeña
for n=1:size(r,2)
    rectangle('Position',prop(r(n)).BoundingBox,'EdgeColor','r','Linewidth',1);
end
%encontrar círculos con área grande
for n=1:size(g,2)
    rectangle('Position',prop(g(n)).BoundingBox,'EdgeColor','g','Linewidth',1);
end
% imprimir las posiciones de los centroides sobre la imagen
for n=2:Ne;
    Centro(1,:)=prop(n).Centroid
    h=text(Centro(1),Centro(2),num2str((prop(n).Centroid)));
    set(h,'Color','w','Fontsize',8);
end
% paso las coordenadas de pixel a mm
j=dicominfo('MR_T2_AX.dcm');
dxy=j.PixelSpacing;

for n=2:Ne;
    H(n-1,:)=[prop(n).Centroid]*[dxy(1):dxy(2)];
end
% graficar las coordenadas
a=H(:,1)
b=H(:,2)
figure();plot(a,b,'o'); 
axis('square');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVZbC.png)